# Click event not working due to "Method does not override method of its superclass" error

Tags: java, android, xml, android-listview, android-listfragment

Based on my list view, I can't debug my app due to an error in my click event. I've seen this error in other questions but the answers are not that relevant to my question. I'm not sure if there is any necessary code missing or not required. What can be done to resolve this error? All help would be appreciated.

**strings**

```
<string-array name="continent_names">
    //item 0    <item>@string/africa</item>
    //item 1    <item>@string/asia</item>
    //item 2    <item>@string/europe</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="continent_descriptions">
    //item 0    <item>@string/africa_description</item>
    //item 1    <item>@string/asia_description </item>
    //item 2    <item>@string/europe_description </item>
</string-array>
```

**FragmentWorld.java**

```
    public class FragmentWorld extends ListFragment implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {

    private WorldListAdapter mAdapter;

    public FragmentWorld() {
        // Required empty constructor
    }

    public static FragmentWorld newInstance() {
        return new FragmentWorld();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_world, container, false);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        initialize(view);
        return view;
    }

    List<World> list = new ArrayList<World>();
    private void initialize(View view) {
        String[] items = getActivity().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.continent_names);
        String[] itemDescriptions = getActivity().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.continent_descriptions);
        for (int n = 0; n < items.length; n++){
            World world = new World();
            world.setID();
            world.setName(items[n]);
            world.setDescription(itemDescriptions[n]);
            list.add(world);
        }

        mAdapter = new WorldListAdapter(list, getActivity());
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                // get the adapter, then get the name from the adapter at that position
                WorldListAdapter adapter = (WorldListAdapter) parent.getAdapter();
                String country = adapter.getItem(position);

                if (mTwoPane) {
                    setItemNormal();
                    View rowView = view;
                    setItemSelected(rowView);

                    Fragment newFragment;
                    if (country.equals(view.getResources().getString(R.string.africa))) {
                        newFragment = new FragmentAfrica();
                    } else if (country.equals(view.getResources().getString(R.string.asia))) {
                        newFragment = new FragmentAsia();
                    } else if (country.equals(view.getResources().getString(R.string.europe))) {
                        newFragment = new FragmentEurope();
                    } else {
                        newFragment = new FragmentAfrica();
                    }
                    WorldActivity activity = (WorldActivity) view.getContext();
                    FragmentTransaction transaction = activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    transaction.replace(R.id.detail_container, newFragment);
                    transaction.commit();
                } else {
                    Intent intent;
                    if (country.equals(view.getResources().getString(R.string.africa))) {
                        intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AfricaActivity.class);
                    } else if (country.equals(view.getResources().getString(R.string.asia))) {
                        intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AsiaActivity.class);
                    } else if (country.equals(view.getResources().getString(R.string.europe))) {
                        intent = new Intent(getActivity(), EuropeActivity.class);
                    } else {
                        intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AfricaActivity.class);
                    }
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        // Set up search view
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_world, menu);
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
        searchView.clearAnimation();
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        searchView.setQueryHint(getResources().getString(R.string.search_hint));

        View close = searchView.findViewById(R.id.search_close_btn);
        close.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_action_content_clear);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String newText) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        mAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
        return false;
    }
}
```

**WorldListAdapter.java**

```
public class WorldListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

    private List<World> mData;
    private List<World> mFilteredData;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ItemFilter mFilter;

    public WorldListAdapter (List<World> data, Context context) {
        mData = data;
        mFilteredData = new ArrayList(mData);
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFilteredData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        return mFilteredData.get(position).getName();
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_dualline, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
            holder.description = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_description);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.title.setText(mFilteredData.get(position).getName());
        holder.description.setText(mFilteredData.get(position).getDescription());

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (mFilter == null) {
            mFilter = new ItemFilter();
        }
        return mFilter;
    }

    /**
     * View holder
     */
    static class ViewHolder {
        private TextView title;
        private TextView description;
    }

    private class ItemFilter extends Filter {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(constraint)) {
                results.count = mData.size();
                results.values = new ArrayList(mData);
            } else {
                //Create a new list to filter on
                List<World> resultList = new ArrayList<World>();
                for (World str : mData) {
                    if (str.getName().toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                        resultList.add(str);
                    }
                }
                results.count = resultList.size();
                results.values = resultList;
            }
            return results;
        }


        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            if (results.count == 0) {
                mFilteredData.clear();
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            } else {
                mFilteredData = (ArrayList<World>)results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Error**

> Method does not override method of its superclass

Comment: The error specifies a specific method - look at it's signature, you must've changed one of the argument types or the return type. For `@Override`-annotated methods, they must match the overridden method exactly or this exception will be thrown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class `ListFragment` does not have an `onItemClick()` method. It has an `onListItemClick` method. Change the first argument from `AdapterView<?> parent` to `ListView parent`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83035/discussion-between-sweder-schellens-and-macaronlover).